# Relation between different data distribution and ML models

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, modeling

Despite the generalized linear models incorporate different distributions (e.g. Gaussian, Poisson, etc.) into the modelling process, I am not sure similar usage exists in machine learning. And it seems other than the iid assumptions, all those statistical distributions are so irrelevant in ML modelling. Are there any instances where statistical distribution can incorporate with ML models? Or is there such an application? What are the relation between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ML models define their own conditional distributions ($p(y|x)$ for discriminative modeling, $p(x)$ for generative modeling etc.), likelihood of which is maximized with the training data (or for deriving the posterior in bayesian analysis). I see ML as a generalization of probabilistic modeling where the distribution itself is inferred from the data, often without any assumptions. Here the fact data comes from an unknown distribution, which can not be easily modeled, acts as an impetus for using more expressive neural networks as distributions.

In this case common statistical distributions often act as strong priors for parameters (such as in bayesian neural networks) and in that way, the parameter space essentially becomes a multivariate statistical distribution.

On the other hand, I have sometimes seen examples where parameters of statistical distributions (eg. $\mu$, $\sigma$ in case of normal distribution) are framed as the outputs of a neural network and computed by training it. In this case, we make assumptions that the data comes from a certain, fixed distribution and learn its parameters via flexible ML modeling. This can often take the form complicated hierarchical statistical modeling as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! 2 outstanding questions stem from your answer: 1) How to impose the prior with statistical distribution, according to 'act as strong priors for parameters' you mentioned? Please exemplify. 2) You mentioned 'parameters of statistical distributions are framed as the output of NN', but the output of NN is considered to be the prediction for a particular input sample. So essentially here becomes 'the output parameters change from time to time depends on the particular samples fed into the NN as input at particular time', but est. parameters should be constant?

Comment: For 1), are you familiar with bayesian neural networks? They basically assume a normal distribution for each weight element instead of a single value and update with data.

Comment: For 2), you have to interpret the neural network a bit differently. I can readily cite an example of [VAEs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114) which use encoder-decoder type architecture and the encoded representation learnt there is basically parameters of a gaussian (or whatever dist defined) from which the data came from. From this parameters you try to sample an element and decode it using the decoder.

Comment: well-explained thanks! You definitely deserves the best answer!

Comment: Thanks. But note that I only gave a superficial answer to a very broad topic with many subtleties. I feel that things only start to become clearer when you get exposed to some applications. Feel free to ask for more clarifications or other more specific questions. Cheers!